# Umbraco Partial Views - Call child elements of a child element

Tags: c#, umbraco, partial-views

I need to call the child elements of a child element in Umbraco using Partial views.

I have a page (Homepage) where I can add an element to (Row) and I am adding another element to the row (Col)

i.e.

1. Homepage
   1.1 Row >
   1.1.1 Col1,
   1.1.2 Col2

   1.2 Row >
   1.2.1 Col1,
   1.2.2 Col2,
   1.2.3 Col3,

I have a partial view to call the rows -

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
        var root = Model.Content;
        var rowsPage = root.Descendants("Row"); //Child Element Name

            if(rowsPage.Count()>0)
            {
                <div class="container">
                    @foreach(var node in rowsPage)
                    {
                        <div class="row" style="background:red; margin-top:30px;">
                            @(Html.Partial("Columns"))
                        </div><!--/.row-->
                    }
                </div><!--container-->
            }

 }
```

So this will display the number of rows which are child elements of the Homepage i.e. 2

Then in here I want to call another partial view which displays the columns

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
    @{
        var root = Model.Content;
        var columns = root.Descendants("col"); //Child Element Name

        //var columns = CurrentPage.Descendants("col"); //Child Element Name


            if(columns.Count()>0)
            {
                <div class="">


                    @foreach(var node in columns)
                    {


                        <div class="@(node.GetPropertyValue("columnWidth"))" style="border:1px solid red">

                            <h2>@(node.GetPropertyValue("colTitle"))</h2>
                            <p>@(node.GetPropertyValue("colBody"))</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="@(node.GetPropertyValue("colButtonLink"))" role="button">@(node.GetPropertyValue("colButtonText"))</a></p>
                        </div><!--/.col-->


                    }
                </div><!--/.-->


            }

        }
```

So the first row would include 2 columns and the second row would include 3. But at the moment using this code it is displaying 2 rows but including all of the cols in both.

I think it is the following lines where I need to call only the child elements of the row but I am unsure of how to do this.

var root = Model.Content;
**var columns = root.Descendants("col"); //Child Element Name**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First try to understand different between "Descendants" vs. "Children".Please try this example:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
        var root = Model.Content;
        var rowsPage = root.Children("Row"); //Child Element Name

            if(rowsPage.Count()>0)
            {
                <div class="container">
                    @foreach(var node in rowsPage)
                    {
                        <div class="row" style="background:red; margin-top:30px;">
                            @(Html.Partial("Columns",node))
                        </div><!--/.row-->
                    }
                </div><!--container-->
            }

 }
```

then for column partial view:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
    @{
        var rowNode = Model;
        var columns = rowNode.Children("col"); //Child Element Name

        //var columns = CurrentPage.Descendants("col"); //Child Element Name


            if(columns.Count()>0)
            {
                <div class="">


                    @foreach(var node in columns)
                    {


                        <div class="@(node.GetPropertyValue("columnWidth"))" style="border:1px solid red">

                            <h2>@(node.GetPropertyValue("colTitle"))</h2>
                            <p>@(node.GetPropertyValue("colBody"))</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="@(node.GetPropertyValue("colButtonLink"))" role="button">@(node.GetPropertyValue("colButtonText"))</a></p>
                        </div><!--/.col-->


                    }
                </div><!--/.-->


            }

        }
```

Comment: I have received the error -  CS1928: 'Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent' does not contain a definition for 'Children' and the best extension method overload 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentExtensions.Children(Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent, System.Func<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent,bool>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Which is highlighting this section - var rowsPage = root.Children("Row"); //Child Element Name

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of any resources which will help?

Comment: try " using Umbraco.Web; "